# How to put image into another image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an empty-white image1 with size specified with CSS and I want to put another image2 inside it which has no styling. So my problem is when the second image is smaller or bigger than image1, I guess my question is how to adjust image2 to fully fit with image1.

I should use CSS or javascript(if possible) only.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: wrap them both in a container, then give them both `width: inherit; height: inherit;`

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 3):

```
 <div style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <img src="a.jpg" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;"/>
  <img src="b.jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 70px;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to explain the concepts behind it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style type="text/css"> 
.imgA1 { position:absolute; z-index: 1; } 
.imgB1 { position:absolute; z-index: 3; } 
</style>

<img class=imgA1 src="imageA.jpg">
<img class=imgB1 src="imageB.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width` and `max-height` for both and wrap them in a div! In my example, whatever the size, (first, child is smaller than the parent, second, child is larger than the parent), both fit accordingly. And it is in pure CSS.

```css
img {max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; display: block;}
.parent, .child {position: absolute;}

#p1 {width: 350px; height: 150px; left: 0; top: 0;}
#c1 {width: 350px; height: 150px; left: 0; top: 0;}

#p2 {width: 350px; height: 150px; left: 0; top: 200px;}
#c2 {width: 350px; height: 150px; left: 0; top: 200px;}
```

```html
<div id="p1" class="parent"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></div>
<div id="c1" class="child"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt=""></div>

<div id="p2" class="parent"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt=""></div>
<div id="c2" class="child"><img src="http://placehold.it/450x450" alt=""></div>
```